# Once published my website javascript can't start

Tags: jquery

i've got a problem with javascript on a website i'm creating, it's only html and css3 and a bit of jquery for a slider and a gallery.

Slider 1: http://www.petitcoeur-champoluc.it/test/inverno.html

Gallery: http://www.petitcoeur-champoluc.it/test/lo_lilla.html

It all works in local, but once uploaded online jquery doesn't execute and nothing shows up.

The code used is not the same for the slider and for the gallery, it comes from two different sources.

Please help me guys, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: make sure you have read/execute access privileges for folder where script files reside...

Comment: this wont help but you are trying to add jquery twice (1.6.2 and 1.7.1)

Comment: ALWAYS check the console for errors: `$(".flexslider").flexslider is not a function`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are loading jQuery twice in page, once at top and again at bottom. The second version over writes the first. along with the plugins that are now part of the jQuery object so the plugin methods no longer exist

Comment: That eas very simple! thank you guys, it was because of the twice loading, it's the first time i use this boilerplate... :-)